# creating associations rails during CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I have a model with associations. How to create/update the associations as CRUD operations are performed on the model.

That is, when I run

```
@v1_seller = V1::Seller.new(seller_params)
@v1_seller.save
```

It should save the associations.
Should I create after_create hooks and pass the params (but then I will have to do the same in update)? Or am I missing something? I feel that it should be done automatically in rails.

currently I am doing it explicitly:

```
@v1_seller = V1::Seller.new(seller_params)
if @v1_seller.save
   @v1_seller.assign_categories(params)
```

my seller model:

```
class V1::Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories, :class_name => 'V1::Category', dependent: :delete_all
  has_many :category_names, :class_name => 'V1::CategoryName', through: :categories

  # right now I am manually calling this after a create/update operation in my controller
  def assign_categories(params)
    params.require(:seller).require(:categories)
    params.require(:seller).permit(:categories => []).permit(:name, :brands => [])

    self.categories.clear

    params[:seller][:categories].each do |c|

      if c[:brands].nil? || c[:brands].empty?
        next # skip the category if it has no brands associated with it
      end

      category_name = c[:name]
      category = V1::Category.new
      category.category_name = V1::CategoryName.find_by(name: category_name)
      category.seller = self
      category.save
      c[:brands].each do |b|
        begin
          category.brand_names << V1::BrandName.find_by(name: b)
        rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
          # skip it. May happen if brand is already added to the particular category
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And `V1::Cateogry` model:

```
class V1::Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category_name, :class_name => 'V1::CategoryName', inverse_of: :category
  belongs_to :seller, :class_name => 'V1::Seller', inverse_of: :category
  has_many :brands, :class_name => 'V1::Brand', dependent: :delete_all, inverse_of: :category
  has_many :brand_names, :class_name => 'V1::BrandName', through: :brands, inverse_of: :category

  validates :seller, :uniqueness => {:scope => [:category_name, :seller]}
end
```

Comment: show please `V1::Category` model

Comment: at first: the method `assign_categories` is for the service not for model. at second: for what do you clear categories? just write a method which will merge categories with persisted ones, and recreate categories that isn't yet exists.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you need `nested attributes`.

Checkout the docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html